# Disable Numlock

Tags: numlock

I've just started using a program that needs the numberpad activated, so I've been using NumLock on my laptop (<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>NumLk</kbd>).  But now, every time I turn off my computer and turn it back on, NumLock is activated when I don't want it to be.

How do I stop this from happening, and only activate NumLock when I command it?

Answer (score 3):

Install `numlockx`:

```
sudo apt install numlockx
```

Run this command:

```bash
numlockx on
```

Or add to `~/.xinitrc` or any started files, like `.profile`, `zprofile`..., that run after `X` login

Answer (score 3):

You can set in `gnome-tweaks` in section `keyboard and mouse -> additional layout options -> additional options for compatiblity -> Numlock always returns numbers` and uncheck it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutuion here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock

You can switch off after login, not from BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu 22.04

You can use `gsettings` and tell Gnome to remember the NumLock state by executing this from the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard remember-numlock-state true
```

Answer (score 0):

That is often controlled by a BIOS setting, so it might not be anything to do with Ubuntu at all.  So reboot and press the `Del`, `F12`, or whatever key works on your system to get to the BIOS screens, and then poke around and see if there is a NumLock setting.  Good luck.